# Armar palabras con letras especificas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando armar algo en lo que pueda darle al codigo unas letras que ingrese el usuario (por ejemplo ) y por medio de alguna funcion ver si esas letras coinciden con alguna palabra (que podrian estar en un objeto o api).

Por ejemplo le doy codigo "a", "c", "a", "s" y el codigo encuentra que esas letras pueden armar la palabra "casa" o "saca". Se entiende a donde quiero ir? Intente armando un objeto con unas pocas palabras para probar y usar la funcion includes() pero solo da resultado si las palabras estan en orden.

Hago un edit y agrego el codigo que por ahora voy usando:

```js
const diccionario = [
  "computadora","saca","casa","ama","baba","larga","arma","coso","oso","hombro","leo","enfermo","curado","vacuna","libros","expertos","invierno","verano","mesa","cerveza","telefono","empresa","señal","costo","arancel","deuda","informe","certificacion","legalizacion","botella","agua","pava","axioma","whisky","reza"
]

input = document.getElementById('input')
button = document.getElementById('button')

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  filtrados = diccionario.filter(e => e.includes(input.value))
  console.log("coincidencias encontradas:" + filtrados)
})
```

```html
<html>
  <input type = "text " id="input"> <button id='button'>Click</button>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola folz33. Un gusto. Vas a necesitar un "diccionario" de palabras correctas contra lo cual matchear. ¿Tenés ese diccionario? ¿Como es? ¿Es un array?

Comment: Un gusto tambien. Ese diccionario todavia no lo tengo, tambien lo estoy buscando. Por ahora estoy probando con un array que hice con varias palabras para probar coincidencias.

Comment: Deberías incluír lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Hay varias cosas que se pueden hacer dependiendo exactamente que quieres hacer. Lo mas performante hasta donde entiendo el problema que explicas, sería almacenar un hash asociado a la combinación de letras que formann las palabras, y comparar la entrada con dicho hash.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, ahi pude hacer un edit y le inserte el codigo provisorio que estoy manejando por ahora.  Mientras voy a ir investigando esto del hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al comentario, se podría comparar hash con hash, te dejo una prueba de concepto para que sirva de idea:

```js
const diccionario = [
  "computadora","saca","casa","ama","baba","larga","arma","coso","oso","hombro","leo","enfermo","curado","vacuna","libros","expertos","invierno","verano","mesa","cerveza","telefono","empresa","señal","costo","arancel","deuda","informe","certificacion","legalizacion","botella","agua","pava","axioma","whisky","reza"
]


const hash = (palabra) => palabra.split("").sort().join("");

const diccionario_hash = diccionario.map(e => hash(e));

const busca_coincidencias = (palabra) => {  

  let resultado = [];

  const hash_palabra = hash(palabra);

  diccionario_hash.forEach((e, i) => {

    if (e === hash_palabra) { // <-- comparación hash con hash
      resultado.push(diccionario[i]);
    }

  })
  
  return resultado;

}


console.log(busca_coincidencias("acas"));
console.log(busca_coincidencias("osoc"));
```

Si esto habría que hacerlo con un diccionario real, es decir cientos de miles de palabras, hay varias cosas a considerar. Primero que nada, tanto el diccionario como el hash deberían ser almacenados e indexados en una base de datos. La query también se realizaría sobre la base de datos. Osea que de JavaScript no quedaría casi nada.
El hash que incluí es simplemente una prueba, es el string ordenado, para los fines del ejemplo es suficiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo veo bastante improbable de llevar a la practica entonces.

Comment: @folz33 no era mi intención desanimar, llevar la idea a algo mucho mas grande no es taan dificil como podría parecer.